# Create a table if given a procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a table in a database based on a procedure that was created. I am not to familiar with MySQL procedures to be able to try and create this database.

Here's the code for the procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SetChanProps(IN vchanmask TEXT, in vchankey TEXT, IN vcommentxt TEXT, IN ventrymsg TEXT, IN vexpires TIMESTAMP, IN vgroupname TEXT, IN vchanlimit INT, IN vmodes TEXT, IN vonlyowner INT, IN vsetbynick TEXT, IN vsetbyhost TEXT, IN vsetbypid INT, IN vtopic TEXT, IN vkickexisting INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE msgid int;
DECLARE rowcount int;
DECLARE setondate TIMESTAMP;
SET setondate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rowcount FROM `chanprops` WHERE `chanmask` = vchanmask;
if rowcount > 0 THEN UPDATE `chanprops` SET `chankey` = vchankey, `comment` = vcommentxt, `entrymsg` = ventrymsg, `expires` = vexpires, `groupname` = vgroupname, `limit` = vchanlimit, `mode` = vmodes, `onlyowner` = vonlyowner, `setbynick` = vsetbynick, `setbyhost` = vsetbyhost, `setbypid` = vsetbypid, `topic` = vtopic, `setondate` = setondate WHERE `chanmask` = vchanmask;
ELSE INSERT INTO `chanprops` (`chanmask`,`chankey`,`comment`,`entrymsg`,`expires`,`groupname`,`limit`,`mode`,`onlyowner`,`setbynick`,`setbyhost`,`setbypid`,`topic`) VALUES (vchanmask,vchankey,vcommentxt,ventrymsg,vexpires,vgroupname,vchanlimit,vmodes,vonlyowner,vsetbynick,vsetbyhost,vsetbypid,vtopic);
end if;
SET msgid = 36;
select matrixqueue(msgid,vchanmask,vchankey,vcommentxt,ventrymsg,Unix_Timestamp(vexpires),vgroupname,vchanlimit,vmodes,vonlyowner,vsetbynick,vsetbyhost,vsetbypid,vtopic,Unix_Timestamp(setondate),vkickexisting);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Is this the correct line to gather what I need to make this table?

```
ELSE INSERT INTO `chanprops` (`chanmask`,`chankey`,`comment`,`entrymsg`,`expires`,`groupname`,`limit`,`mode`,`onlyowner`,`setbynick`,`setbyhost`,`setbypid`,`topic`) VALUES (vchanmask,vchankey,vcommentxt,ventrymsg,vexpires,vgroupname,vchanlimit,vmodes,vonlyowner,vsetbynick,vsetbyhost,vsetbypid,vtopic);
```

Would I then use the CREATE PROCEDURE line (Line #2) to determine that types for the the column IDs?

Unfortunately, the project I am trying to utilize this procedure on hasn't been worked on in years and has been abandoned by its creator. They've included other .sql files that usually just create the tables for me. They seemed to have missed this one which conveniently is the one I really care about.

Comment: Probably parameters types: `IN vchanmask TEXT, in vchankey TEXT, IN vcommentxt TEXT, IN ventrymsg TEXT, IN vexpires TIMESTAMP, IN vgroupname TEXT, IN vchanlimit INT, IN vmodes TEXT, IN vonlyowner INT, IN vsetbynick TEXT, IN vsetbyhost TEXT, IN vsetbypid INT, IN vtopic TEXT, IN vkickexisting INT`

Comment: You have this procedure, but the table got lost? Yes, you can use those as a starting point for the table structure (although it might contain more columns, specifically `setondate`, used in the update-query). Also, `text` is oftentimes a placeholder type for a `varchar` (of yet unknown lengths). An important missing piece is the primary key. It might be an autoincrement or one of the other columns (although probably only `chanmask` makes sense), you may be able to figure that out by looking at the content (or other code using this table).

Comment: @Solarflare I tried looking around the project on github but not having any luck. The project this is from is https://github.com/Masaq-/Openspy-Core

Comment: Well, I am not going to analyze that repository for you. If that table isn't used anywhere else, you probably do not need it (and that might explain why they forgot about it), otherwise you may need to analyze that other code using that table and/or just wait until you get an error when that code gets executed (e.g. other missing columns). But just creating that table with the information you currently have seems like a working approach.